# Wait-ActivityFunction fails periodically

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, powershell-core

I have several PowerShell durable functions running. Every now and then, some of them fail on the `Wait-ActivityFunction` step. I have wrapped this step in try-catch, and can pinpoint the exact error.

The workers always return an array. I can be empty or it can contain a range of well formed objects.

The error looks like this:

```
PS> $err.Exception

Message        : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'input')
ParamName      : input
TargetSite     : System.Object ConvertFromJson(System.String, Boolean, System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], System.Manageme
                 nt.Automation.ErrorRecord ByRef)
StackTrace     :    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JsonObject.ConvertFromJson(String input, Boolean returnHashtable,
                 Nullable`1 maxDepth, ErrorRecord& error)
                    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Utility.TypeExtensions.ConvertFromJson(String json) i
                 n /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Utility/TypeExtensions.cs:line 139
                    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Durable.DurableTaskHandler.GetEventResult(HistoryEven
                 t historyEvent) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Durable/DurableTaskHandler.cs:line 209
                    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Durable.DurableTaskHandler.WaitAll(IReadOnlyCollectio
                 n`1 tasksToWaitFor, OrchestrationContext context, Action`1 output) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Durable/
                 DurableTaskHandler.cs:line 131
                    at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Durable.Commands.WaitDurableTaskCommand.EndProcessing
                 () in /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Durable/Commands/WaitDurableTaskCommand.cs:line 37
                    at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoEndProcessing()
                    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.Complete()
Data           : {}
InnerException :
HelpLink       :
Source         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility
HResult        : -2147467261
```

My process looks like this:

```
        $tasks = foreach ($j in $MyJobs) {
            Invoke-ActivityFunction -FunctionName 'MyWorker' -input $($j | ConvertTo-Json) -NoWait
        }
        try {
            $Result = Wait-ActivityFunction -Task $tasks
        }
        catch {
            $errorLog = New-TemporaryFile
            $_ | Export-Clixml $errorLog
            Out-StorageBlob -Container debug -BlobName '{0}/Error.clixml' -File $errorLog
        }
```

How can I debug this error further?

A clixml export of the $tasks variable looks like this:

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Durable.Tasks.ActivityInvocationTask</T>
      <T>Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Durable.Tasks.DurableTask</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <ToString>Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Durable.Tasks.ActivityInvocationTask</ToString>
  </Obj>
  <Obj RefId="1">
    <TNRef RefId="0" />
    <ToString>Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Durable.Tasks.ActivityInvocationTask</ToString>
  </Obj>
  <Obj RefId="2">
    <TNRef RefId="0" />
    <ToString>Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Durable.Tasks.ActivityInvocationTask</ToString>
  </Obj>
  <Obj RefId="3">
    <TNRef RefId="0" />
    <ToString>Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Durable.Tasks.ActivityInvocationTask</ToString>
  </Obj>
  <Obj RefId="4">
    <TNRef RefId="0" />
    <ToString>Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Durable.Tasks.ActivityInvocationTask</ToString>
  </Obj>
...
  <Obj RefId="2490">
    <TNRef RefId="0" />
    <ToString>Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Durable.Tasks.ActivityInvocationTask</ToString>
  </Obj>
  <Obj RefId="2491">
    <TNRef RefId="0" />
    <ToString>Microsoft.Azure.Functions.PowerShellWorker.Durable.Tasks.ActivityInvocationTask</ToString>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

The $MyJobs content is a slow changing array of well formed objects.

**Update 2022-01-16 6:30**

Zooming in on the `Wait-ActivityFunction -Task $tasks` it turns out, that there are some empty activities in the `$tasks` variable.

Wrapping the call like this works:

```
$Result = $tasks | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        Wait-ActivityFunction -Task $_
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}
```

Now, the orchestrator returns my data every time. But comparing a file that generates an error in the code block above and one that does not, reveals, that one or more lines are missing.

So the question that remains is, why does some tasks start and then fail in this very intrusive way?

Comment: I just saw the exception occurs in `ConvertFrom-Json`. Where do you get `$MyJobs` from? Some of them appear to be null.

Comment: All jobs come from a previous API call that retrieves well formed objects. I'll update the question with a clixml export of the tasks.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue except that I am using 'Invoke-DurableActivity',
I suspect that it is related to the return value of the activity function... I also do believe that my activity function is returning something 'not null' however I really suspect that I got an error exception and it returns a null value to 'Wait-ActivityFunction' which throwing this exception